# Delete all files (except hidden files) in a folder

Tags: delete

I need to delete all directories and files, except hidden files like *.htaccess* from this directory:

```
generated/code
```

I tried this:

```
rm -rf generated/code/*
```

but I get ***rm: cannot remove 'generated/code/Magento/Framework': Directory not empty***

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. There was a cronjob running in the background, writing to that folder, thats why it failed to delete.

1. Stop cron service

   ```
   sudo service cron stop
   ```
2. Delete directory

   ```
   rm -rf generated/code/*
   ```
3. Start cron service

   ```
   sudo service cron stop
   ```